# jQuery conflict with iframe and parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am loading a external page ( same in my domain ) in to a div using jQuery load function. Both pages will have individual roles also , ie the child page has its own functions ( works as an individual page ) and it will load in div also. The page structures as

1st page ( parent )

```
<html>
<head>
<script>JQUERY HERE</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="to_load_second_page"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd Page

```
<html>
<head>
<script>JQUERY HERE</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contents"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Individually both pages are working fine. but once after loading the 2nd page in 1st's div the jQuery functions of 1st page doesn't working.

I think when the child loads in second page again the jQuery.js get added in parent. But we cant avoid to loading of this jquery.js because the child page also need to run individually for that jquery.js is needed.

Please help how to solve this issue

Thank you for your time 
:)

Comment: In the title you say "iframe" but from your description it sounds like you're `.load`ing an entire HTML page into a div on your page. Are you actually using an `iframe`?

Comment: sorry Gustav Carlson ... I am using .load to load an entire html page in a div....

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery's `.load()` to append content to an existing element, you don't want to fetch an entire HTML document, but rather just the new markup to be injected in the existing page. Note however that jQuery will make sure that `<script>` tags in the fetched HTML fragment *are* executed in the global context (that of "page 1", where you already have jQuery available!) so you can organize the contents of page 2 like so:

```
<div id="contents"><!-- Contents here --></div>
<script>
    /* JS you want to execute - but don't include jQuery.js here - 
       it's already available and including it again will overwrite the
       existing object, making any plugins originally included unavailable!
     */
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but at the time of running page2 individually need jquery.js for its functionality ... :(

Comment: It's used both "standalone" and `.load`ed into page 1? Then you should either display it in an `iframe` when embedding it or, preferably, make it possible to serve the contents both with the entire HTML structure (for standalone use) and without (for AJAX). How that's best done depends entirely on your server side environment.